# Center .page-desc button created with CSS

Tags: html, css, button, center, squarespace

I'm trying to center a button, in Squarespace, made from CSS and a link in the page description.

I've used the code provided at [This Squarespace Question](http://answers.squarespace.com/questions/33950/custom-button-over-thumbnail-marquee) . It gets the button perfectly, but it ends up really skewed.. [link](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2eeh9wo.jpg)

Does anyone know any code can I use to dynamically center the button (Page Description link) in screen like other marquee examples like madebybump.com?

I've tried Margins, padding, and position: block, but none of this work and end up graying out in the CSS editor.

Thanks!!

Comment: I do not see what you are talking about. Page Description link??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the rest of your code. But here's 2 ways:

1. if you have specified the width of the button. Try to add this style to the button: `margin: 0 auto;`
2. Or create a div tag where the button will be placed inside. And add those style to the div:

   `float:left;
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0):

```
.example-btn{
     width:100px;
     height:1000px;
     line-height:100px;
     border:1px solid red;
     overflow:hidden;
     text-align:center;
     position:relative;
 }
```